# What's the best way to send email to a large list where each email is to be personalized with information from a database and other sources?

Tags: php

I run a daily deals aggregator. I'd like to send daily emails to users who sign up for them. The site itself is PHP/MySQL. What should I use to send emails? Each email will be specific to each user depending on the kind of deals that user wants to received. What do sites like Quora or other daily deal sites use to send emails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What methods exist for setting up a large email notification system?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096217/what-methods-exist-for-setting-up-a-large-email-notification-system)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use loops to loop through the emails that are stored in an array where the keys of the array are the respective user ids, and then send emails accordingly. You can use the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table in your database to temporarily store the addresses that have not yet received a mail and create a cronjob that sends 200 email per 30 minutes or so. Like this you can avoid clicking some button and wait for hours until your script is done.

Remove every address that has received the mail until your table is empty. Use another cronjob that runs every week or month (cycle to send newsletter) that fills the temporary table with your recipient addresses.